# Store files on server and download them automatically when Android app is installed

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, apk, assets

I am making a Educational app for students of different classes from 9-12. Right now all the study materials are stored in the app itself so the size of the app is increased. Here is the screenshot:-

All the data is stored in html format inside 'assets' folder
[image]

These are the notes for all the students for each subject
[image]

I want to store these the whole assets folder on server and when the app is installed I want to automatically download the 'assets' folder to user's mobile so that the size of the apk file is reduced. Currently the size of the app is 11 MB, in which about 5 MB is for the assets folder and till now I have just added materials for class 10 and still I have to add content for class 9,11,12. And also i have to add more contents for class 10 so later on my app size will increase.This is the link to the app:-

[1Learn NCERT App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nammatech.onelearnclasstenn)

The app I am developing is kind of offline app where the user need not to be connected to internet so for the first time when the app is installed I want to sync the files from server to user's mobile but from next time the app will use the downloaded files and no need of Internet connection.
I don't want to use obb files, Is there any other method to do it?

Comment: Downloading files is discussed every day on stackoverflow. So what exactly is your problem? I see no problem in doing what you want.

Comment: You did not tell us the total size of the html files.

Comment: The size of app right now is 20 MB but I want to decrease its size more. The asset folder is itself taking 5 MB for class 10 notes so I want to move the asset folder to server and when the app is installed then it will download all the files from server in user's mobile. In this way the size will get reduced.

Comment: Sorry the size of app now is 11 MB.

Comment: The files should get downloaded automatically like it gets downloaded for many games but not in obb type, Is there any other method?

Comment: Of course. You can download files. What is the problem exactly? I asked that before.

Comment: How to download these files in mobile, I am not getting codes?

Comment: As said before: how to download a file is pretty standard and has been treated a hundred times in stackoverflow. So what is your problem? Just start with one file.

Answer (score 1):

Try expansion files. More info here https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files. It solves a lot of the problems with hosting large files by using Google Play. I am not sure if your main app must be >100 MB for extension files to be allow. Give it a shot let me know.

Comment: I don't want to use obb files, Is there any other method?